# How do I perform a basic op-amp DC sweep analysis in LTspice?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, simulation, spice, netlists

I want to simulate a simple approximation of an op-amp with an LTspice netlist, as required by my professor.

Circuitlab allowed me to confirm that this circuit outputs -2×Vin at node 003, but I can't get it working in the other simulator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjFoDw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the netlist I've written:

```
Vin 0 N001 10
R1 N001 N002 100
R2 N002 N003 200

Eopamp N003 0 0 N002 100000

.dc Vin 0 100 0.1

.backanno
.end
```

Unfortunately, when I hit "simulate", I get a popup that says "DC sweep: source 'vin' not found".

What is the intended syntax for a DC sweep?

Comment: Your circuit and your spice net have Vin reverse from each other.  In Spice it's `V{name} {+node} {-node} [[DC] {value}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most versions of Spice, the first line is an **obligatory comment** and is ignored.  (Actually it's the name of the circuit, and shows up in the output.)  I believe this is your problem: as your first line `Vin` is interpreted as a comment line.  Simply add a new first line.

This file

```
none's circuit

Vin 0 N001 10
R1 N001 N002 100
R2 N002 N003 200

Eopamp N003 0 0 N002 100000

.dc Vin 0 5 0.5
.control
run
print v(N001), v(N002), v(N003)
plot v(N001), v(N002), v(N003)
.endc
.end
```

Worked fine with ngspice, and made this graph:
[image]

And this output:

```
$ ngspice nonenone.cir
[...]
** ngspice-37 : Circuit level simulation program
Circuit: none's circuit

Doing analysis at TEMP = 27.000000 and TNOM = 27.000000


No. of Data Rows : 11
                                 none's circuit
                                 DC transfer characteristic  Mon Nov 14 14:35:12  2022
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Index   v-sweep         v(n001)         v(n002)         v(n003)         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0   0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    0.000000e+00    
1   5.000000e-01    -5.00000e-01    -9.99970e-06    9.999700e-01    
2   1.000000e+00    -1.00000e+00    -1.99994e-05    1.999940e+00    
3   1.500000e+00    -1.50000e+00    -2.99991e-05    2.999910e+00    
4   2.000000e+00    -2.00000e+00    -3.99988e-05    3.999880e+00    
5   2.500000e+00    -2.50000e+00    -4.99985e-05    4.999850e+00    
6   3.000000e+00    -3.00000e+00    -5.99982e-05    5.999820e+00    
7   3.500000e+00    -3.50000e+00    -6.99979e-05    6.999790e+00    
8   4.000000e+00    -4.00000e+00    -7.99976e-05    7.999760e+00    
9   4.500000e+00    -4.50000e+00    -8.99973e-05    8.999730e+00    
10  5.000000e+00    -5.00000e+00    -9.99970e-05    9.999700e+00
```

Comment: Thank you. I get the feeling that quirks like "the first line is a mandatory comment" are very common in older software

Comment: In fact, the first line is the name of the circuit, as you see in the output, but it's pretty much just a comment.  In [PALASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PALASM) it was the first three lines which were ignored.

Comment: @nonenone  It's in the manual.  Both the [original SPICE3 manual](http://bwrcs.eecs.berkeley.edu/Classes/IcBook/SPICE/UserGuide/description_fr.html) and [the LTspice help (press F1)](https://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/A_General_Structure_and_Conventions.htm) mention it, although since LTspice is newer it takes more liberties with how the first line and `.end` line are dealt with.  I'm guessing you took an existing LTspice netlist (generated from schematic) and deleted everything before the `.backanno` and `.end`, including whatever the first line was.